# Need api to pull the last uploaded item to the COS bucket

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to pull the last uploaded object to COS, but there seems to be no ideal API to do the same.

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not possible to get the COS bucket uploaded items by SL API.

However you can try with boto3 library of python to get the COS bucket items, see the following documentation.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-python#python-examples-list-objects

Comment: Your post does not answer the question. The API provided does not provide the functionality requested.